# Points following an axiom

Tags: mathematics, geometry

**Your aim:**

Mark any finite number of points on a plane. It should meet this axiom.

**Axiom:**

*Original way of stating it:* If a line (infinite) is drawn passing through exactly n (n>0) points, any line drawn parallel to it will pass through exactly n or 0 points.

*New way of stating it:* If **any** 2 parallel lines are selected, either one (or both) of them passes through zero points, or they pass through the same number ($n$) of points.

**Don't my original and new way of stating the axiom mean the same thing?**

Comment: Infinitely many points are OK?

Comment: This appears to be a plain old math problem. Consider whether text-book style problems are appropriate http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/are-math-textbook-style-problems-on-topic

Comment: this is any square $n$X$n$ plan permeated by $k$<$n²$ perpendicular lines to each other and to plan axes , where all the points taking part of these lines are removed from this plan .

Comment: I'm not sure how to classify this problem. It looks like an elementary geometry problem (not even a problem, maybe); if so, should be moved to another SE or deleted. If it is a lateral-thinking puzzle, then the tags are wrong, also I can't see anything outside the box here. I'm very confused.

Comment: in my view , it is too easy for a puzzle , only if i did interept it properly

Comment: Where do the points come from and are the first $n$ points the same as the second $n$ points? If we can pick any different $n$ points for the line and its parallel then it's trivial to find an example where the axiom holds (and it's equally simple to find one where it doesn't), see Ben Frankel's answer. If the parallel is supposed to go through the same $n$ points then see leoll2's answer.

Comment: This could be a slightly interesting question about finite geometries, but you need to define "line" and "parallel" in that context, if that's what you meant. (Parallel would likely just mean not intersecting. Line is harder to define.) If you're just using Euclidean geometry, then "axiom" is the wrong word.

Comment: This is clearly just asking for clarification on a textbook definition.

Comment: I have been **misunderstood**. *1.* It is not a textbook problem. I made it myself and I know how parallel lines work. *2.*  I'll edit the question to make it more clear what I wanted to ask, please see.

Comment: Your restatement of the axiom is not identical. Its "points" are too vague. Every line passes through points. You need to choose specific arbitrary points.

Comment: Additionally, if you choose all your points at random, you could easily construct a scenario in which one line passes through two points and a parallel lines passes through one. This is because you have made your "points" vague. The original wording very clearly makes the set of points dependent on "these points are on $L_1$". Any line $L_2$ that is parallel to $L_1$ now definitely intersects either *all* or *none* of the points on $L_1$. The key difference is that the point set is tied to the first line instead of being an arbitrary point set which is not necessarily plotted linearly.

Comment: This is still not a puzzle. It belongs on Math SE (or maybe even a technical writing blog).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, below is a simple set of points satisfying the condition. Points in the set are red. Parallel lines are of the same color.

---

[image]

Comment: Also any set of $n > 1$ collinear points would work..

Answer (score 1):

> In geometry, parallel lines are lines in a plane which do not meet. (source [**here**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_(geometry)))

The parallel line will always pass through exactly $0$ points of the other line, else they wouldn't be parallel!
Example:
[image]

**What if the two lines coincide?**  They both pass through the $n$ points, but they're called *coincident* and not *parallel*